# Float Bug in Safari for Windows

Tags: html, css-float

I'm trying to float a bunch of divs so they line up next to each other. But for some reason in Safari 4.0.4 for Windows, the divs are dropping about 25px lower than the previous one. So gradually each div gets lower and lower.

**Please see this screenshot: http://marckimmel.com/img/float-bug.jpg**

Everything works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

I'm not doing anything especially tricky with the code. Simply a relative div floated left.

Comment: Can you post the code? When I try to reproduce locally with four floated `div`s on a simple page they line up.

Comment: Hi Adam, it's rather complicated to show just the pertinent code, but you can view the page I'm working on here: http://marckimmel.com/about.html

Comment: It appears cufón is putting tags between each of the divs that push the following one down. It's also happening on Safari 5.0.4 for Mac.

Comment: Ah you're right! Thanks Adam. Cufon has been creating wierd spacing issues in other places of the site too. Will have to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this fixed by giving the following css properties to floating elements:

```
display:inline;
height:1%;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
height:1%;
```